# Hook for deinstallation of QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have a plugin that creates a lot of settings in the Options | Advanced dialog.

I'd like to clean up a little on plugin install.

Is there a hook I could use ?

`unload()` is run on any QGIS shutdown and therefore not feasible.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS has a plugin managment tool. 
[image]

On the menu, you can scroll in a list containing all of your plugin. You can uninstall the one that is problematic.

[image]